# How can I search within my own questions?

Tags: support, status-completed, search

I'd like to do a search restricting the results to my own questions. I checked out the search tips and discovered this recommendation:

> Advanced Super Ninja Search Options
>
> posts from a specific user `user:1234 apples oranges`

So I tried...

```
user:Ethan vim  # I'm trying to find a question I asked about Vim a while ago.
```

There were many results, but none were questions of mine, at least not on the first page.

What's the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way is to use `user:me`.

Or you will need to use your numeric user ID, not your name.

- On Meta SO, 130286.
- On SO, 42595.
- On SF, 11478
- On SU, 2176

So it would be `user:42595 vim`. [Doing this on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A42595+vim), currently, your question is the only result which pops up. :)

Comment: Thanks, John Smithers. I forgot about that shortcut. :)

Comment: Would be great if that `user:me` was added to the "Advanced Super Ninja Search Options"...?

Comment: I didn't know about `user:me`, now I don't have to remember my user ID

Answer (score 3):

Use your UserId instead of your username.

If you hover over your username, look for the Id portion. /users/**YourId**/YourUsername

There are a lot of registered users named Ethan on StackOverflow, the site distinguishes you based on your UserId, not your display name.