# How to search only within my questions on SO?

Tags: feature-request, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I search within my own questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27487/how-can-i-search-within-my-own-questions)

How to search only within my questions on SO?

Comment: @ChrisF - you missed a bit (questons -> questions). Anyone with 2k care to edit?

Comment: @Dominic - Damn! I missed that one. Firefox does highlight errors in text boxes, but it does in text areas.

Comment: You always manage to post poorer quality dupes: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27487/how-can-i-search-within-my-own-questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=

Under the Advanced Super Ninja search options, it mentions being able to use:

> user:84201

I put your user id number in there and you should only get questions you have posted in with that in your search terms. You can also apply this is to any user id and get all question only by a certain user.

And Dominic Rodger reminds us of the shortcut also:

> user:me

Comment: There's also a handy shortcut - `user:me`.

Comment: ok , but how to search from a keyword withing my answers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me  i opened this and then i inserted "jquery" in search box but it's not showing my questions only

Comment: @Jitendra - type `user:me jquery` into the search box, the search box doesn't remember previous searches.

Comment: @Dominic Rodger - Thanks very much

Comment: or to search within the jquery tag, use `user:me [jquery]`