# TextBox to search our own questions and answers instead of playing around with the URL?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, answers, search

I was about to ask for a way to search within my own questions and answers when I found these interesting question and answer: **[How can I search within my own questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27487/how-can-i-search-within-my-own-questions)**

That said, it seems we have to use some URL tricks and inputing our *userId* in the URL, etc. I wonder:

1. **Is it not getting a little too tricky just to search our own questions and answers?**
2. **Would it not be simpler to have a TextBox control to simply input the keywords we're looking for?**
3. **I'm here now asking whether the SO community would be interested in such a feature which could make SO even simpler to use, in my humble point of view?**

I do believe this would be a little more intuitive than tricking the URL, particularly when it doesn't seem to show any guidelines anywhere outside asking on Meta about the way we may use the URL to query SO.

*By making this kind of search easier in our user profile page, this would make it nice to refer to our own questions or answers instead of rewriting code samples over and over again.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a URL trick. You don't even need your own UserId if you're logged in. As pointed out in the question you linked, just enter into the search textbox in the top right `user:me` to filter your search to only posts from you. You can do this from anywhere in the site as long as you're logged in, and in combination with any other search you want.

If you're not logged in, the UserId can be found in your profile and so `user:<id>` works. It helps to devise a handy method to memorize your own UserId - then you won't even have to look it up. That said, you could always make the process easier by logging in and using the first method.

The site will also pre-fill the search box with `user:<id>` when visiting a user's profile – including your own. You take advantage of this to save yourself some typing when you want to search within a particular user's posts.

Comment: +1 Thanks, this works! Besides, I just found it in the FAQ, after you mentioned how to use the `user:me` in the search box. I think it is not obvios to find out. It's somehow counter intuitive, in my humble opinion. Anyway, this works! =) Thanks!