# search a question or answer in my profile page

Tags: discussion, feature-request, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TextBox to search our own questions and answers instead of playing around with the URL?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72798/textbox-to-search-our-own-questions-and-answers-instead-of-playing-around-with-th)

I need to search on my profile page for question or answer I have asked or answered previously.  If I come across a familiar question and I think I have answered it previously, then I need to search and post the link to my answer. I cannot go through all the answers or questions manually.

Answer (score 3):

You can look for your posts using the search textfield.
You can use "user:me" to look for your posts, and "is:answer" or "is:question" to search only your answers, or your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's why the search field on your profile page has "user:857361" text in it. Add some search keywords to it and you will search in your posts only.

Comment: How to search for only accepted answers matching the search criteria

Comment: @userSeven7s: See http://stackoverflow.com/search, advanced search options.

Comment: Yes found out a moment ago.. Thanks