# Search within my own questions for the entire Stack Exchange network

Tags: support, search

I learned that adding 'user:me' can help me search within my own questions.

[How can I search within my own questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27487/how-can-i-search-within-my-own-questions)

But this seems to work only for a specific site.

Applying the search term 'user:me' at the top search bar at stackexchange.com does not seem to work.

How can I search within all my questions across the entire Stack Exchange network sites?